# Can I apply a CIFilter to ARkit camera feed?

Tags: cifilter, ios11, arkit

I'm trying to apply a blur effect to camera live steam image in ARSCNView. I have checked the WWDC videos. They only mentioned the custom rendering with Metal, but I didn't found any complete example on web. Any idea how to do that?

---

Updated 1
I have tried to apply a filter to the background. It show incorrect orientation. How can I fix this?

```
let bg=self.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage

        if(bg != nil){
            let context = CIContext()
            let filter:CIFilter=CIFilter(name:"CIColorInvert")!
            let image:CIImage=CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: bg!)
            filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let result=filter.outputImage!
            self.sceneView.scene.background.contents = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent)

        }
```

Comment: It might be that you can use Post Processing in SceneKit with ScnTechnique;  I have not tried it myself.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique

Comment: Looks like the the live stream image is set as the scene background and I'm not sure how to add filters to it. You also have access to the pixel buffer through sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage so you might be able to apply the filter to it and update the background

Comment: @Guig Thanks! Its work! I can apply some CIFilters on the background now! But the orientation is incorrect...

Comment: If you don't mind fiddling with YCbCr pixelbuffers, [this solution works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919745/reliable-access-and-modify-captured-camera-frames-under-scenekit)

Answer (score 5):

I've found a pretty good solution, which is to simply apply a corresponding geometric transform to the `background` property whenever the device orientation changes:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage)
    filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let context = CIContext()
    if let result = filter.outputImage,
        let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent) {

        sceneView.scene.background.contents = cgImage
        if let transform = currentScreenTransform() {
            sceneView.scene.background.contentsTransform = transform
        }
    }
}

private func currentScreenTransform() -> SCNMatrix4? {
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .landscapeLeft:
        return SCNMatrix4Identity
    case .landscapeRight:
        return SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi, 0, 0, 1)
    case .portrait:
        return SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        return SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Make sure you call `UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()` in your `viewDidLoad` method first.

Comment: Hello, I want to integrate color filter using CIFilter in ARKit, I have tried with above code but at run time, output is getting stretched, i have already posted on it, please have a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501761/live-camera-is-getting-stretched-while-rendering-using-cifilter-swift-4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can try this

```
let bg = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage
    if (bg != nil) {
        let context = CIContext()
        let filter:CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert")!

        let image:CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: bg!, options: nil)

        let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent)!
        let uiImage:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
        let resultImage = CIImage(image: uiImage)?.oriented(forExifOrientation: imageOrientationToDeviceOrientation(value: UIDevice.current.orientation))

        filter.setValue(resultImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        let result = filter.outputImage!
        self.sceneView.scene.background.contents = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent)
    }


func imageOrientationToDeviceOrientation(value: UIDeviceOrientation) -> Int32 {
            switch (value) {
            case .portrait:
                return 6
            case .landscapeLeft:
                return 1
            case .landscapeRight:
                return 3
            default:
                return 6
            }
        }
```

Comment: this solution works but impractically slow on a iPhone7P

Comment: I tested it on the iPhone 6, 6S and 7, it was all right

Comment: For me it skyrockets frame time from 2ms to 20ms on an iPhone7P. What are your measurements?

Comment: How did you measure?

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` set `self.sceneView.showsStatistics = YES;` [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522763-showsstatistics) then run app and tap the '+' to open it up

Comment: Hm... yep, it's 20ms.. But visually the picture does not slow down.. Can you give us other solution?

Comment: Not yet, still looking. Keep an eye on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919745/reliable-access-and-modify-captured-camera-frames-under-scenekit)