# ARKit – How to detect the colour of specific feature point in sceneView?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I would like to get the colour of the detected world object at a specific feature point in the sceneView. For example, I have a feature point detected at `(x:10, y:10, z:10)`.

How do I get the colour of the `object`/ `surface` at this position?

Comment: could you include in your question the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible to get a colour of a real-world object under feature point using ARKit methods (the same way like you saw in many compositing apps). There's no ARKit method allowing you multiply an `Alpha` of a feature point by `RGB` value of corresponding pixel in a video stream.

[image]

`.showFeaturePoints` is an extended debug option `ARSCNDebugOptions` for an ARSCNView. This option just allow you to show detected 3D feature points in the world.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
public static let showFeaturePoints: SCNDebugOptions
```

> But I'm sure that you can try to [apply a CIFilter to ARKit camera feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624937/can-i-apply-a-cifilter-to-arkit-camera-feed) containing feature points.

Feature points in your scene are yellow, so you can use [Chroma Key Effect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/applying_a_chroma_key_effect) to extract an Alpha channel. Then you need to multiply this Alpha by RGB from camera. So you'll get `color-coded` feature points.

[image]

You can alternatively use a `CIDifferenceBlendMode` op from [Core Image Compositing Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIDifferenceBlendMode). You need two sources – one with feature points and another without them. Then you have to modify this result of Difference op and assign it to Alpha channel before multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am trying some photogrammetric applications using ARKit like your first image shown. Gonna have some researches on your method.